# passport-linkedin-oauth2 upgrade to Linkedin API v2 with r_liteprofile in scope

Tags: passport.js, passport-linkedin

I am trying to retrive lite profile of a user using passport-linkedin-oauth2 and am passing r_liteprofile as scope, all the fields except email are being returned as undefined.

Please help with the migrations required in passport-linkedin-oauth2 that are required as per Linkedin API v2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq

Answer (score -1):

If you are using V2 and you did not taken permission to use r_basicprofile 
then either apply for permission  to use r_basicprofile  to linkedin 
or use r_liteprofile + r_emailaddress

r_liteprofile for firstName,lastName,profilePicture,id - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))

r_emailaddress  for getting  emailAddress - https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))

Check this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: i had already shared the link in question, i am looing for code change in passport fn

Comment: If you are looking to configure the `passport-linkedin-oauth2` strategy, can you share the code you have server side and if possible the error log?

Comment: Please check this may be this will help you :https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2